# About my class and why it's not detecting java.awt.Color?

Tags: java, awt, draw

I've got a issue with the program I'm writing - this is an APCS A class so there is an APCS.lib - it includes the DrawingTool Class that is used in the program. I'm having issues with the import java.awt.Color statement:

There is a driver that is executed for the entire program but my question is in the line import java.awt.Color; and line 33 - pencil.SetColor(Color, red); . Not sure my drjava is not detecting that java.awt.color import and still giving me a "cannot find symbol/variable error." The program draws a house.

```
//Name£∫ Allen Li
//Date: Monday, September 9th, 2013
//Purpose: Using apcslib to draw a house on with a piece of paper and pencil. 

import apcslib.*;
import java.awt.Color; 
public class DrawHouse{

  private DrawingTool pencil;
    private SketchPad paper;

 /**
  *  Basic constructor for DrawHouse.  
  *  Instantiates paper and pencil to basic
  *  values.
  */
 public DrawHouse(){
  paper = new SketchPad(300, 400);
     pencil = new DrawingTool(paper);
 }

   /**
     *  The draw method for the DrawHouse class.  
     *  This method will run all of the
     *  commands necessary to draw the house.
     *
     */

   public void draw(){

     // draw the main house
     pencil.setWidth(3); 
     pencil.setColor(Color, red); 
     pencil.down(); 
     pencil.move(-100,0); 
     pencil.move(-100,100); 
     pencil.move(100,100); 
     pencil.move(100,0); 
     pencil.move(0,0); 

     //door

     pencil.up(); 
     pencil.move(-20,0);
     pencil.down(); 
     pencil.move(-20,50); 
     pencil.move(20,50); 
     pencil.move(20,0); 

     //roof
     pencil.up(); 
     pencil.move(-100,100); 
     pencil.down(); 
     pencil.move(0,150); 
     pencil.move(100,100); 


     //window left
     pencil.up(); 
     pencil.move(-70, 60); 
     pencil.down(); 
     pencil.move(-40, 60); 
     pencil.move(-40, 90); 
     pencil.move(-70, 90); 
     pencil.move(-70, 60); 

     //window right
     pencil.up(); 
     pencil.move(70,60); 
     pencil.down(); 
     pencil.move(40,60); 
     pencil.move(40,90); 
     pencil.move(70,90); 
     pencil.move(70,60); 
     pencil.up();





   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the given answers:

The setColor method requires a single `Color` object as its parameter.  You cannot pass it `Color`, as that is a class, and you cannot pass it `red`, as that doesn't mean anything to the compiler (it tries to find a variable named `red`).

The trick is to access the static variable `Color.red` or `Color.RED` (which is a `Color` object), and pass it into the method, as the other answers have done.  As mentioned in another answer, the [javadocs for `Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) may help you here.

Answer (score 2):

java.awt.Color has a constant `red`. It should be

```
pencil.setColor(Color.red);
```

in line 33. Have a look at its the [javadoc for `Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error where you have `pencil.setColor(Color, red);`

This line should be:  `pencil.setColor(Color.RED);`

By the way welcome to SO!